# Variable in stage not set

Tags: azure-devops

my goal is to define a variable in the parent script in Azure DevOps for my pipeline, that I can read it within the template script.

I tried this:

```
stages:
  - stage: Download_Suppliers_Artifacts
    variables:
      buildVersion2: test2
    jobs:
      - template: /Pipelines/Templates/download-components-hcp5.yml
```

Within my script I tried to access it but it is empty:

It is not showed here:

```
- task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'env | sort'
```

Nor here:

```
- task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: '{{ variables.buildVersion2}}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the Runtime expression syntax for variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax

In your case, you could directly use macro syntax `$(var)` instead of template expression `${{ variables.var }}`

Test sample (Parent script)

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest


stages:
  - stage: test
    variables:
     buildVersion2: test2
    jobs:
      - template: download-components-hcp5.yml
      - job: 
        steps:
         - script: echo $(buildVersion2)
```

Template:

```
# download-components-hcp5.yml
jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
      - script: env | sort
      - powershell: echo $(buildVersion2)
```

[image]

[image]